# Apple Store, can I finish transaction from server side, after verifying receipt

Tags: app-store

Client is sending receipt to server, for server->apple veryfication, and adding platinum points to his acc.

Is it possible to finish transaction from server side? I sometimes have some problems with finishing it from client side.